# Geometry area calculation ( gdal GetArea() )

Tags: python, gdal

I'm trying to calculate the area of a polygon (given in lat/long coordinates) in Python by use of the `gdal` package, but I'm wondering what the standard units are of the output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://gdal.org/doxygen/classOGRSurface.html

says:

> Returns:
>   the area of the feature in square units of the spatial reference system in use.